# Is there a recommend way to get Spring 2.5+ to autowire Hibernate domain objects

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm, inversion-of-control

Is there a recommend way to get Spring 2.5+ to autowire Hibernate (3.0+) domain objects. I realize that there is a way to do this using AspectJ (`@Configurable`), but I would like to avoid pulling in AspectJ.

Some Googling found [this DependencyInjectionInterceptorFactoryBean class](http://fisheye1.atlassian.com/browse/springframework/spring/sandbox/src/org/springframework/orm/hibernate/support/DependencyInjectionInterceptorFactoryBean.java) but it seems to just live in the sandbox (and just in 2.0.x?).

I can create a 10-line Hibernate `PreLoadEventListener` to do this autowiring for me, but I really assumed it would be something that `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3` provided.

Answer (score 2):

The *recommended* way to provide dependency injection to instances beyond Spring's control is to use the AspectJ-based solution you mentioned. As far as I know, the Hibernate-specific classes have been abandoned in favour of the general approach described [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2008/01/23/new-improvements-in-domain-object-dependnecy-injection-feature/).

Also note that you don't need `@Configurable` if you use `AbstractInterfaceDrivenDependencyInjectionAspect`. As you said, you *will* need to use AspectJ either for load-time or compile-time weaving. As a benefit, you will get dependency injection for "corner cases" like deserialization as well with that approach.

For a comprehensive example of how the patterns suggested by Ramnivas can be implemented and integrated, have a look [here](http://87.230.78.21:8080/download/attachments/1179684/JUGC.zip).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the @Repository (and @Component) annotation(s). With Spring 2.5, the concept of "stereotype" annotations introduced in Spring 2.0 has been extended and these annotations are all supported by the new component-scan functionality as explained in the [Annotation-driven configuration](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/new-in-2.html#new-in-2-ioc-annotations) chapter of Spring documentation.

So this should work:

```
@Repository
public class HibernateClinic implements Clinic {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public HibernateClinic(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public Collection getVetTypes() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return session.createQuery(”from VetTypes”).list();
    }
}
```

(Sample taken from Rossen Stoyanchev's [presentation](http://springone.wiki-neon.adaptavist.com/download/attachments/1212485/S08_11_03_05.pdf) at Metropolis 2008)

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.  You're autowiring the repository, not the domain objects.

Answer (score -1):

Could you give a code example?

I find the whole 'anaemic domain model' anti-pattern difficult to implement. I think it sounds great in theory but not so great in practice.

What factors have led you to take a rich domain model approach?

Comment: "The [...] anti-pattern is difficult to implement? This sounds strange. Is this what you wanted to say ?